# Azure Maps and IoT Hub

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-maps

So I have settled up a RPI 3B with Windows IOT Core, a GPS module, wrote a C# program where I can get GNGGA data: packet those in json format and sent it to IOT Hub (stored in blob storage).

Now I want to visualize those data in a map, pointing the position of the device. I have studied for days about azure maps but I didn't find any solution...

The goal is to point to IoT hub or my blob storage (maybe with a stream analytic function(?)) where I can read LATITUDE e LONGITUDE data from my json's and set the pointer (of location required) in azure's map.

In docs I didn't find anything particular/specific whith this purpouse. Any help, idea, suggestion?

thank you very much

Comment: at the end did you find my answer useful and how did you approach your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this is going to be helpful, maybe if you provide more details I can update my answer. Nevertheless, I will suggest some approaches to your problem:

**1.** Azure Stream Analytics have built-in [geo-spacial functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/announcing-real-time-geospatial-analytics-in-azure-stream-analytics/) that could be very handy in working with such data. ASA also provide an [integration with Power BI online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#power-bi). Using these features you could develop a solution that displays your data on a map in Power BI. Some guidelines could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guided-learning/visualizations?tutorial-step=1#step-5).

**2.** The second approach in general is to consume the Bing Maps API with a Web HTTP request. This could be accomplished in several ways: **(A)** after you parse your data in Stream Analytics, you could output it to a Function App and make a Web HTTP request; **(B)** It is also an option to trigger a Function App directly as an endpoint listener to your IoT Hub and make the same thing; **(C)** And [a third option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-monitoring-notifications-with-azure-logic-apps) would be to route your messages to a Service Bus endpoint, then attach a Logic App and again make your HTTP request.

Comment: Hi Vladislav, thank you very much for your reply! I will try those approaches during this week (my university classes will start tomorrow, so it will take a bit too long) I will update you as soon as possible if those suggestion have satisfied my issue :) thanks again!

Comment: You might also find this documentation useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps Once you get the data to the browser it is pretty easy to visualize it on the map. Here is an example of taking JSON data and visualizing it on a map: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/default.aspx#Create%20Pins%20from%20Custom%20JSON

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the Azure IoT solution accelerators: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/about-iot-accelerators These are templated projects that are great starting points.